# How to access an image in Vue src folder using JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue app where I want to access some image files in an included JS file for various purposes, e.g. one of which is adding images to a canvas element.

This would normally be easy using something like the following:

```
function getImage() {
  let img = new Image();
  img.src = '/assets/images/bg.jpg';
  img.onload = function () {
    //
  };
}
```

I can technically access images in my public folder this way, but what if I want to access compiled image assets from my src folder rather than public folder?

In CSS I can simply use an @ symbol in the path like `@/assets/images/bg.jpg` (as this is configured as an alias in the vue config) so I tried...

```
img.src = '@/assets/images/bg.jpg';
```

...but this doesn't work.

Is there a way to achieve this, or is what I'm trying not possible? Perhaps assets referenced purely in JS aren't included in the build process? Thanks

Comment: Usually you don't want to put images in the `src` directory, as that gets 'compiled' into your bundle. Could you not put the assets within `public`?

Comment: @Lissy93 if it's the only option then yeah, I just normally have my image assets in src - it's useful if any get updated as when building they get given unique file names etc.

Comment: Did either of the below answers help? If so, you should accept one, and if not, you should specify more details as to what's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this out, and it does in fact work.

```
<img src="@/assets/my-image.png" />
```

However since this is compiled, you won't be able to set / change the image src dynamically with JS like you're doing in your example above.

Comment: Yeah, this works in CSS and inline HTML, but not in JS unfortunately - looks like what I wanted may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

With webpack you can do this:

```
img.src = require('@/assets/images/bg.jpg');
```

During the build it will be replaced with a path to the compiled asset.

Comment: This results in the error
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`
I guess Vue is limited to only ES module imports.